# Search people by name from other tenant in Microsoft Teams

Tags: office365, microsoft-teams

We have more than one tenant in Microsoft Office 365 and we want people from one tenant to be able to search people by name from the other tenant. We already tried to add contacts (in Users > Contacts at the Office 365 management console) and it works fine in Outlook but it does not work in Teams, can't find the person by name when creating a meeting for example). I tried to invite a guest user (it creates the user in Users > Guest Users) and i can search the user by name in Teams, but when i open a chat and start sending messages this messages are not seen by the other tenant user. Could it be that they are different users?!

So, is there any way i can make the users searchable by name, in Teams, from different tenants?

Answer (score 0):

As long as you have a Cross-tenant access setup (Both Tennants have to do the same) you can search by the name of the persons in the other tenant.

In my case, on the other hand, the search by name only works if the user has already established a chat via direct chat or via a team with our tenant.